# I`m doing a to do application on javascript, but when I add one more to do comes the value undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I`m having a problem to get the value that the user had input
I`m doing this app that it`s a list of todo`s 
but I`m getting undefined as I add elements to the array

I`m getting like:
Fazer cafe
Estudar Javascript
Acessar Comunidade da Rocketseat
undefined

```
    /* VARIABLES */
    var listElement= document.querySelector("#app ul")
    var inputElement = document.querySelector("#app input")
    var buttonElement = document.querySelector("#app button")

    var todos=[
        "Fazer cafe",
        "Estudar Javascript",
        "Acessar Comunidade da Rocketseat"
    ];
    /* Function that render the to dos when added */
    function renderTodos(){
        listElement.innerHTML="";
        for (todo of todos){
           var todoElement = document.createElement("li");
           var todoText= document.createTextNode(todo);

           todoElement.appendChild(todoText);
           listElement.appendChild(todoElement)
        }
    }

 /* Renders in html */    

    renderTodos()

/* Function to add TODOS */
    function addTodo(){
        var todoText= inputElement.Value;

        todos.push(todoText);
        inputElement.value=" ";
        renderTodos();
    }
```

Comment: `inputElement.Value` the `value` property of input elements is lowercase, js is case sensitive

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much, I`m looking at this code for 2 hours, and I couldn`t see the value with highercase V